# Common table expression from last child record

Tags: sql-server-2008, parent-child, hierarchy, common-table-expression

Hi I have an sitemap table and a hierarchy table.

```
    USE [EB_NEW]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP]    Script Date: 07/24/2013 06:13:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [P_ID] [int] NULL,
    [C_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TYPE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TITLE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TASK_URL_ID] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ON
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (2, NULL, 2, N'EB', N'Employee Benefit', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (3, 2, 3, N'Company', N'Company Listing', 175)
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (4, 3, 4, N'Company', N'Company Profile Setup', 176)
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (5, 4, 5, N'Company', N'Company Policy Setup', 191)
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (6, 4, 6, N'Company', N'Employee Profile Setup', 178)
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (7, 5, 7, N'Company', N'Company Policy Setup 2', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] ([ID], [P_ID], [C_ID], [TYPE], [TITLE], [TASK_URL_ID]) VALUES (8, 6, 8, N'Company', N'Employee Profile Setup 2', NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[COMMON.SITEMAP] OFF
```

result

```
ID  P_ID       C_ID     TYPE    TITLE                       TASK_URL_ID
2   NULL         2        EB    Employee Benefit              NULL
3   2            3    Company   Company Listing               175
4   3            4    Company   Company Profile Setup         176
5   4            5    Company   Company Policy Setup          191
6   4            6    Company   Employee Profile Setup        178
7   5            7    Company   Company Policy Setup 2        NULL
8   6            8    Company   Employee Profile Setup 2      NULL
```

I used common table expression to determined the hierarchy data

```
WITH ctLevel
                AS
                (
                    SELECT
                        C_ID                                                                AS Child
                        ,P_ID                                                               AS Parent
                        ,1                                                                  AS [Level]
                        ,TASK_URL_ID                                                        As taskUrl_ID   
                        ,TITLE                                                              As title
                        ,TYPE                                                               As Type     
                        ,ID                                                                 As ID                                                       

                    FROM   
                       [COMMON.SITEMAP] as common_sitemap

                    WHERE  
                        P_ID is null and common_sitemap.TYPE ='EB'


                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT 
                        C_ID                                                                    AS Child
                        ,P_ID                                                                   AS Parent
                        ,[Level] + 1                                                            AS [Level]
                        ,TASK_URL_ID                                                            As cTaskUrl_ID
                        ,common_sitemap.TITLE                                                   As ctitle
                        ,common_sitemap.TYPE                                                    As cType    
                        ,common_sitemap.ID                                                      As cID                                                                              

                    FROM   
                        [COMMON.SITEMAP]as common_sitemap


                    inner JOIN 
                        ctLevel
                    ON 
                        ( 
                        P_ID = Child 

                        )

                    WHERE  
                            common_sitemap.P_ID is not null 



                    )

                  SELECT  DISTINCT [Parent] ,[Child], ctLevel.title,ctLevel.Type,

                  ctLevel.taskUrl_ID,
                   ctLevel.Level,
                    common_task_url.TASK_URL
                    FROM   ctLevel 
                    left join   
                    [COMMON.TASK_URL]as common_task_url 
                    on
                     ctLevel.taskUrl_ID = common_task_url.TASK_URL_ID


                    order by Level
```

Result

```
Parent      Child       title                                              Type                                               taskUrl_ID           Level       TASK_URL
----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------
NULL        2           Employee Benefit                                   EB                                                 NULL                 1           NULL
2           3           Company Listing                                    Company                                            175                  2           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyList.aspx
3           4           Company Profile Setup                              Company                                            176                  3           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyDetail.aspx
4           5           Company Policy Setup                               Company                                            191                  4           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyPolicy.aspx
4           6           Employee Profile Setup                             Company                                            178                  4           ~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDetail.aspx
5           7           Company Policy Setup 2                             Company                                            NULL                 5           NULL
6           8           Employee Profile Setup 2                           Company
```

So my question is , is it possible to get the entire related hierarchy record from last child record.For example 
child record is **7**

So result will get

```
Parent      Child       title                                              Type                                               taskUrl_ID           Level       TASK_URL
----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------- -----------------------
NULL        2           Employee Benefit                                   EB                                                 NULL                 1           NULL
2           3           Company Listing                                    Company                                            175                  2           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyList.aspx
3           4           Company Profile Setup                              Company                                            176                  3           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyDetail.aspx
4           5           Company Policy Setup                               Company                                            191                  4           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyPolicy.aspx
5           7           Company Policy Setup 2                             Company                                            NULL                 5           NULL
```

But if the child record is **8**

```
Parent      Child       title                                              Type                                               taskUrl_ID           Level       TASK_URL
----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------- -----------------------
NULL        2           Employee Benefit                                   EB                                                 NULL                 1           NULL
2           3           Company Listing                                    Company                                            175                  2           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyList.aspx
3           4           Company Profile Setup                              Company                                            176                  3           ~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyDetail.aspx
4           6           Employee Profile Setup                             Company                                            178                  4           ~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDetail.aspx
6           8           Employee Profile Setup 2                           Company                                            NULL                 5           NULL
```

Any souliton? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the child record is an input to the query? If so, I would do it in two CTE's. The first one is as you have it to generate all possible paths. The second one will travel up the first tree from the last node to find the one path. This only works if it's a tree. Otherwise, you'll have more than one path in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. It's very similar to how you would traverse down the tree. I've made an example fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/842ce/13

```
declare @childID int = 7;

with tree as (
    select parent, id from T where parent is null
  union all
    select t.parent, t.id from T
    join tree on T.parent = tree.id
), bottomUp as (
    select parent, id from tree where id = @childID
  union all
    select t.parent, t.id from tree t
    join bottomUp on bottomUp.parent = t.id
)
select * from bottomUp
order by id asc
```

Here I am traversing up the tree that I traversed down. However, you don't have to use that first tree if you don't want to. Change tree to T in the bottomUp, and it still works. If you already have logic for trimming the tree going down, you can keep it. If you don't have any logic, it's faster if you only have the second CTE without the first.